# Edit Custom Field Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I need to edit a Custom Field Type (which is greyed out) from Numeric to something that allows me to enter 8 numeric digits only. Currently, it adds a comma. I guess I need integer or something. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's greyed out because changing the type could create lots of issues.  Instead, create a new field of the right type and copy existing data to it.

If you use Alphanumeric you can set the Database Field Length to 8.  That will limit it to 8 characters.  If you want to enforce the digits only restriction then try [hook_civicrm_validateForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/) - see the example on that page.

Comment: Worked perfect! I simply deleted the field and then redid it with your recommendations! Thanks!